# Firebase firestore database not working using console

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Sorry for the basic questions, but I am beginning to use Firebase Firestore databases, and I went over to the console to start to see how to add data etc. However, whenever I add a collection, I just don't see it. I click "start collection", put in an id. Then I add a dummy document. But it just doesn't add. I have a screen that just looks like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

But after I click save it does show up...

I have changed my rules to be like this:

```
// This rule allows anyone on the internet to view, edit, and delete
// all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
// started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
// leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
// requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
//
// Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
// your app will lose access to your Firestore database
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 3, 10);
}
```

I've been trying this for hours, with no luck. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Security rules do not impact the way the console works. You should be able to add data whatever are your security rules. Can you add to your question the different screenshots of all the steps you are executing. I know it is a bit time consuming, but without that it will be really difficult for us to help you.

Comment: If you're having problems working with the Firebase console, you should contact Firebase support directly for assistance, as there might be a bug in the console.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Added more screen shots

Comment: @RJB You should see the document. What happens if you refresh your browser content? Which browser are you using (version/type)?

Comment: chrome and safari didn't work, even after refesh

Comment: You should contact the support then, as Doug has advised.

Answer (score 1):

In my case i figured it was Qustodio internet protection that blocks the request, when i close it the database successfully load.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you're doing it the correct way. Try delete the browser data an login again to Firebase. I just spin up a test project and recorded the steps how to create a new collection. [Video](https://gph.is/g/4bBxlR3)

Let us know if you still having trouble!

Comment: Tried this, didn't work

Comment: Thanks for video though.